# How can I reuse a block to make other ones?

Tags: twig

This is what i want (re-use a block for others in order not to code duplicates too much) :

```
{%- block distance_widget (block_a, block_b, block_c) -%}
    {%- if unit -%}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ unit|default('kg') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock distance_widget %}
```

or it may be done like that (i think extend cant be used within a block but maybe there is another methode that can do this) ?

```
{%- block_a -%}
    {%- extends block distance_widget -%}
{%- enblock -%}

{%- block_b -%}
    {%- extends block distance_widget -%}
{%- enblock -%}

{%- block_c -%}
    {%- extends block distance_widget -%}
{%- enblock -%}
```

this is what i currently have... (a lot too much code duplicats, its ugly i want a clean code so i want to make a re-usable block) :

```
{%- block_a -%}
    {%- if unit -%}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ unit|default('kg') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- enblock -%}

{%- block_b -%}
    {%- if unit -%}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ unit|default('kg') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- enblock -%}

{%- block_c -%}
    {%- if unit -%}
        <div class="input-group">
            {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">{{ unit|default('kg') }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {%- else -%}
        {{- block('form_widget_simple') -}}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- enblock -%}
```

Comment: Take a look at [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html) or [embed](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does the trick (it allows to reuse the already defined blocks) :

```
{{- block('distance_widget') -}}
```